# Symmetry at spatial infinity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, group-theory, asymptotics

One definition for asymptotic flatness is
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu}+\mathcal{O}(r^{-1}),$$
where $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric.

The asymptotic symmetry group is defined as those non-trivial gauge symmetries that preserve the boundary condition.

Writting $\Omega$ as the spherical component of the metric, $x^{\mu}$ for the angular coordinate and $u=t-r$ as the retarded time coordinate at future null infinity. The BMS group can be defined as
$$\hat{u}=K(x^{\mu})(u+\alpha(x^{\mu})),$$

where α($x^{\mu}$) is a regular arbitrary function on the sphere.

My question is, is there such a direct way to display the symmetry group at spatial infinity (SPI group)?

Comment: Maybe this paper answers your question? https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09170